# How to make date fields in app independent of system timezone?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have free style app where I am using date field inside the XML table. The issue is, if I change date-time zone of my system (I am using Windows 10), it also changes date and time of fields inside my app.

What I want to achieve is, independent of my system timezone, date/time of fields inside my app should remain the same, it should not change with my system timezone.

Has anyone achieved this? Thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Use [`moment-timezone`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)

Comment: Cannot use external libraries. Need to solve this using UI5/JavaScript of possible

Comment: You can try to use UTC methods from Date() object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date. Check all the getUTCDate(), getUTCDay() etc...

Comment: You can format your dates with sap.ui.core.DateFormat and set the UTC flag to true, this way all your dates will be consistent with UTC DateTimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the type `sap.ui.model.type.Date` or `sap.ui.model.odata.type.DateTime` in your data binding and specify format options `UTC` equals `true`.

```
<ObjectListItem 
    number="{ 
         path: 'YourProperty', 
         type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date',
         formatOptions: {
            pattern: 'dd.MM.yyyy',
            UTC: true
         }
     }"
 />
```

Reference: [How to handle Edm:DateTime form OData interface in SAPUI5 correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29940222/how-to-handle-edmdatetime-form-odata-interface-in-sapui5-correct).